# Unable to commit to svn with beanstalk on a Mac

Tags: svn, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, beanstalk-svn

I am using Xcode 3.2, Mac OS 10.6 and svn for version control. I am using beanstalk for this svn. I created a repository in beanstalk and made changes in Xcode. When I tried to commit the project from SCM, I got this error:

> Error: 155005 (Working copy not locked; this is probably a bug, please report) Description: Commit failed (details follow):
>   Error: 155005 (Working copy not locked; this is probably a bug, please report) Description: Directory '/Users/Mango3/Documents/Dropbox/splitview/SplitView 2-1 3 2 2/build/SplitView.build/SplitView.pbxindex' is missing
>   Error: 155010 (Can't find a working copy path) Description: Directory '/Users/Mango3/Documents/Dropbox/splitview/SplitView 2-1 3 2 2/build/SplitView.build/SplitView.pbxindex' is missing

I have gone through many forums, but I am still facing the same problem. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably talk to Beanstalk about this.

One thing you can try (it's equivalent to "restart your PC" :) is deleting the local copy, and check it out again. Make sure you keep your local changes safe somewhere, of course. Then copy & paste those changes back in.

Answer (score 0):

Before going through the trouble of backing up your changes and blowing away your working copy, try running the svn cleanup command.  Sometimes working copies just get wrapped up on themselves.